# Sculpting Mesh Problem

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I tried to google a solution to this but had some trouble as I wasn't sure how to describe this problem exactly. I noticed that when I 'over' sculpt an area, the mesh starts to disappear/mess up as shown in this picture. Once this is done, I can't figure out how to fix it as the problem seems to just get worse the  more I play with it. Does anyone have a solution for me and an explanation as to why this is happening?
[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you are sculpting more detail where there is not enough geometry (resolution). Try dyno topo-> constant detail and increase resolution as you need to put more detail in mesh. You can also use eye dropper to see resolution at particular part on mesh and increase if you need.

Comment: @Feenix You are my hero! I hadn't considered that there may not be enough resolution. I had encountered this issue many times and couldn't figure out the solution. Thank you!